# Помогите расположить кнопку так

Tags: html, css, responsive

Помогите, не могу поставить кнопку так,`position:absolute`  не помогает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слишком расплывчасто Дайте код как вы это делали? Что вы пробовали?

Comment: .btn4 {
 position: absolute;
 left:50%;
 width: 25%;
 margin-left: -12.5%;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 25px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bolder;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgb(255,124,110) 1%, rgb(245,49,127) 99%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgb(255,124,110) 1%, rgb(245,49,127) 99%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( -90deg, rgb(255,124,110) 1%, rgb(245,49,127) 99%);
  box-shadow: 0px 11px 29px 0px rgba(255, 7, 95, 0.2);
  width: 371px;
  height: 71px;
}

Comment: пробую сейчас так не получается кнопку поверх блока увести

Comment: Отредактируйте текст вопроса, добавьте html и css

Comment: уже сделал, все равно спасибо за помощь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122581/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0/1122587#1122587

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.slide {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
/* Сделаем разные цвета и чтобы кнока не залезала на контент */
.slide:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <div class="button">I Button</div>
</div>
<div class="slide"></div>
```